# How to Remove/eliminates startup White Screen in React Native For Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-splashscreen

I am getting the white blank screen before the splash screen. I have created my own custom splash screen .After react-native bundle the application a white screen pops up for 1-2 seconds and then splash screen followed by main activity. I have tried almost every solution but nothing is working.
Did anyone face a similar issue after creating a custom Splash screen and solved it?

**MainActivity.js**

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  }
```

Comment: We use [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash) to display our splash screen. We did not notice any white screen before our splash screen using this library

Comment: @sushrut619 Does react-native-bootsplash support animated splash screen

Comment: @sushrut619 Is there any way without using these library?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Splash Screen

I think you can use this package for simplification, just replace with your visual resources https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen

Comment: Thank you @kboskin but i dont want use react-native-splash-screen because in my custom splash screen have  animation and i think react-native-splash-screen cant support animated splash screen

Comment: The actual problem is startup white screen and i want to remove that white screen

Comment: @ijazbacha how about this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-splash

Comment: is there any way without using these library?

Comment: Yes, you can do it using native API provided by platforms
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/specifying-your-apps-launch-screen/
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#:~:text=Starting%20in%20Android%2012%2C%20the,transition%20to%20your%20app%20itself.

Comment: ios working fine but issue in android

Comment: I am quite sure, but in the documentation related to what I've sent above there is a bunch of changes including onCreate of activity

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate

I am not sure if you have applied them but in the original question there is just a default method signature. Please, apply them according to documentation I've posted so that this feature can work